# Space between 2 paths in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, visual-artifacts

How can I align 2 paths perfectly? No matter what I do I get a little space (gap between the 2 paths I create, and they are straight lines not as I saw in other questions with pixel problems)

An example:

[image: Example of gaps between paths]

Between every triangle is a little space, like in the example. It isn't obvious and it doesn't bother, but if I use the image (as an SVG or something) it is really obvious.

Comment: What do paths look like in `Outline Mode`?

Comment: I'm not seeing any space between them in the embedded image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not really affect the way your SVG renderer will draw the image. Its possible that it will outline to white even if there is no gap. This said, you can make the triangles underlap each other, so that each succeeding triangle is behind the other, this should give the **SVG** engine the hint.

Compare:

[image: SVG Preview in Firefox]

**Image 1:** Preview in Firefox. Source: http://imgh.us/tris.svgz

with:

[image: SVG Preview in Firefox with path underlap]

**Image 2:** Preview in Firefox with underlap. Source: http://imgh.us/tris2.svgz

The gap is visible in the screen capture of image 1 between red and orange triangles. But is not in place in the second example as the triangles overlap giving the rendering engine the hint it needs to resolve the issue.