# Gap between two shapes when removing stroke in combined shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This problem has been bugging me for a while now.

I'm drawing two simple shapes (a circle and a curve), I'm drawing these with only a stroke to see the shapes:
[image]

Then I'm using the shape builder tool to create the shapes I really want:
[image]

So now I have 2 shapes (the upper part of the circle and the lower part), let's try filling some colors and then removing the strokes (I don't want any strokes in my final shape):
[image]

Here, if you look closely you can see some kind of a small gap between the 2 shapes where the background shows through. When I change the background's color the gap becomes more clear.

### The question

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here, or even approaching the problem using a wrong method. How should I go about combining shapes without strokes?

**NOTE:**
I tried doing the same thing but with drawing without strokes from the start. The same problem shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is a rendering artefact. All current generation vector renderers suffer form this problem occasionally. It is possible to switch over to a multi sampling rendering engine this eliminates the problem (since theres not really a gap at all). So try save for web with art optimized option and see the artefact disappear.

Another option is to let the shapes overlap (or more accurately underlap). This makes it impossible for the fractional coverage of the engines to fail.

- This has been described in post: [space between 2 paths illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/space-between-2-paths-illustrator/47345#47345)
- I have also described how this SHOULD be done if interaction speed wouldn't be a an issue [here](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/148/how-do-i-accurately-compute-coverage-of-overlapping-analytical-curves/150#150) (computergraphics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks, I get the picture. However, going with the overlapping solution for simple shapes might be easy enough but not for the case I'm concerned with (like [here](http://mrahhal.deviantart.com/art/Oregairu-Hikigaya-Hachiman-573962971)). Saving for web with optimized option seems to solve the issue. Are there any kinds of shortcomings compared to using the "Export" command (even though I'm not really using it for the web)?

Comment: @mrahhal The image you show shouldn't have any problems as it has no need for cutting shapes at all.ypu would naturally overlap and draw inside for shadows.

Comment: I kind of took to drawing everything by cutting shapes and never overlapping stuff (even the image I showed you). Guess I was not doing things in the most appropriate way. Thanks!