# Cant weld object edges on polygonal design (Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I created a polygonal logo using many shapes, which I'm exporting for web in SVG format.

My problem is that, although the edges of each polygonal face/shape is at the same position on illustrator (snapped), when I export for web, a small space appears in between the edges.

In Illustrator, at max zoom:

[image]

On the web browser:

[image]

It seems that each face is disconnected, and that there is a gap between them. On the second image, you can see a bit of white beneath it because the white part extends underneath the shape. You can see it live at http://heropanel.com

How can I solve this? I am using Illustrator CS6.
Can I attribute facets to the same shape and color them individually?

Comment: It is a rendering bug called a conflation artefact. Simply put the rendeing engine is based on a faulty assumption. Make the shapes overlap or use a multisampling renderer that does not have a coverage conflation assunption (Export art optimized). More info [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg/65060#65060),same situation as cut but just for shared edge. Similar issue [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/space-between-2-paths-illustrator/47345#47345). Simple solution: offset paths or manually overlap.

Comment: @joojaa nailed it.  In cases like this I simply overlap the images a smidge.

Comment: @joojaa please avoid answering questions in comments, that's what the answer field is for :)

Comment: @Vincent no i marked it as a duplicate just let the user KNOW what i think the duplicate is