# White space between objects when exporting to SVG in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, svg

I have white space between objects when I export to SVG from Illustrator CC 2015.

I have checked that the lines touches in preview mode and I have exported with 3+ decimals.

What I see in illustrator:
[image: Vector image in illustrator]
What I see in the browser after SVG export:
[image: SVG in browser]

Comment: This is actually a inherent flaw in how most vector engines implement antialiasing. The error is called a conflation artifact. See [this duplicate](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/space-between-2-paths-in-illustrator/) and [this explanation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg) and [this how to circumvent](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches)

Comment: You need to send a small digital Indiana Jones to retrieve it.

Comment: @Joonas Face. Palm.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with SVGs - the transparent line between exactly fitting shapes or between areas which have different colors due blending or transparency, is antialiasing. You can avoid it by having overlapping shapes or inserting something under the seam. One of the shapes a little moved is ok. Even adding a thin stroke helps.