# Inkscape SVG Stroke Size Changing Depending on Zoom

Tags: inkscape, svg, stroke, zoom

**SVG Shape Gaps change when Zooming**

I used this tool: [here](https://stonet2000.github.io/Polytomizator/) to create a low-poly picture and then downloaded it as an SVG. I then noticed that the edges were overlapping and so I brought it into Inkscape where I set the stroke width on each shape to 0.005. This appeared to solve the problem when I was zoomed in as far as possible:

[image]

But when I zoomed out the edges weren't wide enough and so left white lines between the shapes:

[image]

I tried changing the **vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"** on each shape but that made no difference and when I saved it as an SVG and opened it, it still had the gaps:

[image]

I have also seen a question like this where it was all part of the zooming but I still don't know what to do.
Any help, please?

Many regards and thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It's a common rendering bug, an artefact caused by anti-aliasing and not specifically an Inkscape problem. Adobe Illustrator also has similar problems. SVG's viewed in browsers show it too. There's a  similar question with a possible solution/workaround [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/space-between-2-paths-in-illustrator/47345#47345)